# Ipad focus to next input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, ios5

I have three text box for entering the phone number in my form. What i need is when user enter 3 digit in first input field the control should automatically goes to the second input field. It is very well work in my pc using the focus function. But in IPAD it is not working. I think what i need is to have a same function as we click the `next` button in ipad after entering the first input box. I need to make the control automatically to second input field. I googled this issue but most of the forum saying that that the ipad disabled the focus function because of security threat.  Is there any solution to my problem. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [tabindex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_tabindex.asp) ?

```
<input type="text" name="input1" tabindex="1" />
<input type="text" name="input2" tabindex="2" />
<input type="text" name="input3" tabindex="3" />
```

Comment: In this case, he's asking that the focus go to input2 when input1 has been filled - 3 characters. Previously, this could only be achieved through Javascript, but if the focus function is disabled on the iPad, that isn't an option either.

Comment: So dawmail333 Is there any other option other than focus to implement it?